# Данные на странице не успевают обновится после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php

Я решила попробовать сделать грид-панель , что бы люди могли выбрать сколько именно записей им отображалось, но, опять возникли кое-какие трудности.

Что бы сохранить выбор , который сделал юзер , я использую куки. 
Если пользователь переходит по странице : 
videos?section=recent&grid=big , то в куки записывается его выбор , я делаю это так, проверяю, не пуста ли переменная grid, и меняю ее через switch.

```
    if(isset($_GET['grid']))
    {
    $grid = $_GET['grid'];

    switch($grid)
    {
    case 'low':
    $grid4 = 'active';
    SwitchGrid($connect,$s_id,'&grid=low');
    setcookie("grid", 'low', time()+3600, '/');
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['grid'];
    break;     

    case 'medium':
    $grid3 = 'active';
    SwitchGrid($connect,$s_id,'&grid=medium');
    setcookie("grid", 'medium', time()+3600, '/');
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['grid'];
    break;   

    case 'big':
    $grid2 = 'active';
    SwitchGrid($connect,$s_id,'&grid=big');
    setcookie("grid", 'big', time()+3600, '/');
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['grid'];
    }
    }
```

Все окей.В куки все записывается, но, теперь если я в меню перейду, скажем, сначала по ссылке **videos?section=recent&grid=big**, а после этого по ссылке **videos?section=recent&grid=low**, то остальные ссылки, в которых прописана переменная **$cookie** будет иметь значение не нынешнюю low, а big, то-есть, она не обновляется, при переходе на другую страницу , а только если обновить страничку вручную..Я не знаю как это решить , кроме как JS, но его я не знаю, к сожалению.Можете помочь?:D

Если я не очень понятно объяснила, можете сами проверить вот тут, если ссылки конечно не запрещены, там справа грид-панель, а смотреть нужно на ссылки Recent,Popular,Following,Suggestion.

> http://rrcf.tk/videos?section=recent&grid=big

p.s - простите за многобукаф.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас наверняка где-то ошибочная попытка использовать для формирования ссылок только что полученный cookie, который указывает на предыдущий режим grid. А вам нужен текущий.

```
if (isset($_GET['grid'])) {           // получить grid из параметра запроса
   $grid = $_GET['grid'];
} else if (isset($_COOKIE['grid'])) { // или из cookie
   $grid = $_COOKIE['grid'] 
} else {                              // или по умолчанию
   $grid = 'medium';
}                                     // в таком порядке

setcookie("grid", $grid, time()+3600, '/'); // запомнить выбор в cookie сразу же

switch ($grid)
{
    case 'low':
        $grid4 = 'active';
        SwitchGrid($connect,$s_id,'&grid=low');
        break;     

    case 'medium':
        $grid3 = 'active';
        SwitchGrid($connect,$s_id,'&grid=medium');
        break;   

    case 'big':
        $grid2 = 'active';
        SwitchGrid($connect,$s_id,'&grid=big');
}
```

Таким образом в ссылках Recent,Popular,Following,Suggestion можно вообще избавиться от параметра `grid` (а иначе зачем вам вообще cookie?) Или ориентироваться на значение `$grid`.

PHP не знаю. Не знаю какое значение будет в `$_COOKIE['grid']` после `setcookie()`. Скорее всего останется от браузера. Так что уберите использование `$_COOKIE['grid']` в `SwitchGrid()` и в коде после `switch ($grid) {}` отовсюду, где формируются ссылки.

Comment: Все работает , спасибо большое!
И отдельное большое спасибо за разъяснение!